# Swift Equatable protocol default implementation

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, equatable

I check Equatable protocol in Swift source code on Github and as I understand it should provide default implementation for == parameter through extension but i see only (!==, ===, !=) how is it possible?

https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Equatable.swift

Comment: It is the compiler that creates (synthesize) the == function from the properties of the type that conforms to Equatable if possible. If it isn’t possible then we need to implement it ourselves. There can’t be a default implementation because then every type that conforms to Equatable would always have objects that are equal to each other (or not equal depending on the default implementation)

Comment: `===` if for comparing classes only.

Comment: If you like at !=,===,!== you can see these can be defined using == only. That simplifies the coding and ensure for example that != is the opposite of ==